# wanted: simple HTML file that does disclosure triangle <div> hide/reveal

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I have a program that produces a text report. I want it to make an HTML report with multiple disclosure triangles, so that when you click a triangle more of the report shows or hides. I am okay with embedding JavaScript inside the file, but I really want it all in a single file, with no additional files.  Is there an easy way to do this with modern browsers?

Comment: Maybe, depending on what you are doing. What are you having trouble putting into one file?

Comment: I just need a clean, simple example of what to do. There are lots of complicated examples out there. I want something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about compatibility with Internet Explorer, you could use the  html tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Its a very quick way to prototype disclosure triangles.
For example:

```
<details>
  <summary>The contents of the summary tag is always visible</summary>
  <p>Everything else inside the details tag will be hidden in a disclosure triangle</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>.wrapper div { display:none;}</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
     $('.wrapper h2').click(function() { $(this).next().toggle();}); 
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Example header 1</h2>
    <div>bodytext 1</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Example header 2</h2>
    <div>bodytext 2</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Example header 3</h2>
    <div>bodytext 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have made a simple working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NXuQt/1/

It isn't pretty but should give you the simple template you need.

Note that in this solution, the entire header is click-able... I figure adding an image and changing it as part of the click event is something you can take care of yoruself, otherwise let me know :)

Note: The javascript is based on the inclusion of the jQuery library.

EDIT: I updated the answer to copy/paste ready working code, the reason you couldn't make it work as it was, was because i had only taken the essentials from the fiddle example. The fiddle automatically ran the click handler initialization at DOMready, which the updated example now has built in :)

Comment: +1, but you should probably mention you're using jQuery here.

Comment: Huh. This also didn't work when I put it in a stand-alone HTML file, even when I added the <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 to the header and put jquery.min.js in the same directory.

Comment: @yw32: jQuery has a footprint, true, but if you use a cdn hosted version, like the one i use in my updated example, chances are your users will already have it in their browser cache, making the download footprint zero. I also updated my example to fully working code.

Comment: @Martin, I can't use the hosted version if I am providing people with reports that they will run on machines that don't have Internet access. I guess I can put the JQuery in the report directory, but it's ugly, and then people will want to know what the JavaScript is...

Comment: Well, this now works, but I don't have disclosure triangles, so the user doesn't know that it's clickable...

Answer (score 1):

With straight HTML, no. That's not what it's for. You will need to use a scripting language, either JavaScript or VBScript, most likely.

This is a script I've used in the past (not mine, but I don't have the URI of the original):

```
var timerlen = 5;
var slideAniLen = 250;

var timerID = new Array();
var startTime = new Array();
var obj = new Array();
var endHeight = new Array();
var moving = new Array();
var dir = new Array();

function slidedown(objname)
{
    if(moving[objname])
        return;

    if(document.getElementById(objname).style.display != "none")
        return; // cannot slide down something that is already visible

    moving[objname] = true;
    dir[objname] = "down";
    startslide(objname);
}

function slideup(objname)
{
    if(moving[objname])
        return;

    if(document.getElementById(objname).style.display == "none")
        return; // cannot slide up something that is already hidden

    moving[objname] = true;
    dir[objname] = "up";
    startslide(objname);
}

function startslide(objname)
{
    obj[objname] = document.getElementById(objname);

    endHeight[objname] = parseInt(obj[objname].style.height);
    startTime[objname] = (new Date()).getTime();

    if(dir[objname] == "down")
    {
        obj[objname].style.height = "1px";
    }

    obj[objname].style.display = "block";

    timerID[objname] = setInterval('slidetick(\'' + objname + '\');',timerlen);
}

function slidetick(objname)
{
    var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime[objname];

    if (elapsed > slideAniLen)
    {
        endSlide(objname)
    }
    else 
    {
        var d =Math.round(elapsed / slideAniLen * endHeight[objname]);
        if(dir[objname] == "up")
            d = endHeight[objname] - d;

        obj[objname].style.height = d + "px";
    }

    return;
}

function endSlide(objname)
{
    clearInterval(timerID[objname]);

    if(dir[objname] == "up")
        obj[objname].style.display = "none";

    obj[objname].style.height = endHeight[objname] + "px";

    delete(moving[objname]);
    delete(timerID[objname]);
    delete(startTime[objname]);
    delete(endHeight[objname]);
    delete(obj[objname]);
    delete(dir[objname]);

    return;
}

function toggleSlide(objname)
{
    if(document.getElementById(objname).style.display == "none")
    {
        // div is hidden, so let's slide down
        slidedown(objname);
    }
    else
    {
        // div is not hidden, so slide up
        slideup(objname);
    }
}
```

You would assign a call to toggleSlide() to the onclick() event of the element you want to toggle.

Comment: Yep. Sadly enough, I have a friend who works for a relatively large company, and they STILL code ASP pages using VBScript instead of ASP.NET with code-behind. So I had to present that as an option...

Comment: But VBScript doesn't run in most web browsers!

Comment: Precisely why I gave you a JavaScript example. :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function createSection(section, hidden) {
    var triangle = section.children[0]; // assumes the triangle image is the first child of a section (see HTML)
    var contents = section.children[1];
    triangle.onclick = function() {
        if (contents.className.indexOf("hidden") != -1) { // the section is hidden
            contents.className = contents.className.replace("hidden", "");
        } else { // the section wasn't hidden
            contents.className += " hidden";
        }
    }
    if (hidden) {
        contents.className += " hidden";
    }
}

    // Create the sections when window loads
window.onload = function() {
    createSection(document.getElementById("section1"));
    createSection(document.getElementById("section2"), true);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="section1">
    <img src="triangle.jpg"></img>
    <div>This is the section content</div>
</div>
<div id="section2">
    <img src="triangle.jpg"></img>
    <div>this section is hidden by default</div>
</div>
```

Obviously you would have to change some things to your own html file

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some fiddling around, I was able to make a file that does what I want using the `switchcontent.js` and `switchicon.js` javascript files I found at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/switchcontent2.htm

Here's my code, based on editing down theirs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Dynamic Drive DHTML scripts- Switch Content Script II (icon based)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="switchcontent.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="switchicon.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
/* Specifies title style */
.iconspan{
  margin: 3px;
  cursor:hand;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span id="faqtable1-title" class="iconspan"></span>
How hot is our Sun?<br/>
<div id="faqtable1" class="icongroup2">
The surface of the Sun is around 5800 Kelvin, while the core reaches over 15 million Kelvin.
</div>
<br>

<span id="faqtable2-title" class="iconspan"></span>
How big is our Sun in terms of mass?  <br/>
<div id="faqtable2" class="icongroup2">
The contains more than 99.8% of the total mass of our Solar System.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var faqtable=new switchicon("icongroup2", "div") 
faqtable.setHeader('▼', '▶') //Set header HTML
faqtable.collapsePrevious(false) //Allow more than 1 content to be open simultanously
faqtable.setPersist(true, 7) //Enable persistence to remember last switch content states for 7 days
faqtable.init()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this when closed:

```
▶ How hot is our Sun?
▶ How big is our Sun in terms of mass?
```

And this when opened:

```
▼ How hot is our Sun?
The surface of the Sun is around 5800 Kelvin, while the core reaches over 15 million Kelvin.
▼ How big is our Sun in terms of mass? 
The contains more than 99.8% of the total mass of our Solar System.
```